# I only want to add JSON info if condition is met with AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I have a JSON called components.json:

```
{"components": {
    "boardSpaces": [
        {"name":"GO!", "price":0, "position":0, "type":"go"},
        {"name":"Mediterranean Avenue", "type": "property", "price":60, "position":1}, 
        {"name":"Community Chest", "price":0, "position":2, "type":"communityChest"}, 
        {"name":"Baltic Avenue", "price":60, "position":3, "type":"property"},
        {"name":"Income Tax", "price":0, "type":"incomeTax", "position":4},
        {"name":"Reading Railroad", "price":200, "position":5, "type":"railroad"}, 
        {"name":"Oriental Avenue", "price":100, "position":6, "type":"property"}, 
        {"name":"Chance", "price":0, "position":7, "type":"chance"},
        {"name":"Vermont Avenue", "price":100, "position":8, "type":"property"}, 
        {"name":"Connecticut Avenue", "price":120, "position":9, "type":"property"}, 
        {"name":"Jail", "price":0, "position":10, "type":"jail"}]
}}
```

I want to create an array on angularjs that saves each object under `boardSpaces`, but only if the `price` is not equal to 0.  In short, I want an array called `self.board` that saves each object in `boardSpaces` into the array, as long as the `price` is equal to `0`.

Here is my angularjs document:

```
self.board = [];
$http.get('components/components.json').then(function(response) {
    for(space in response.data.components.boardSpaces) {
        if(response.data.components.boardSpaces[space].price === 0) {
            self.board.push(space);
        };
    };
});
```

For some reason, when I tried to loop this in the html page using `ng-repeat`, it doesn't want to work.  I tried this without the condition and it does work, but, for some reason, it won't work together with the `if` statement.

Comment: see if your if condition is satisfied and log the value of self.board, also try printing out the price, (the price might have a different data type for example, and a double '==' might do the trick)

Comment: If you are looking for prices that are different from zero, then the condition should be !==, not ===

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this?

```
$http.get('components/components.json').then(function(response) {
    self.board = response.data.components.boardSpaces.
      filter(function(space) {
        return space.price === 0;
      });
});
```

Or with plain javascript in a working snippet:

```js
var data = {"components": {
    "boardSpaces": [
        {"name":"GO!", "price":0, "position":0, "type":"go"},
        {"name":"Mediterranean Avenue", "type": "property", "price":60, "position":1}, 
        {"name":"Community Chest", "price":0, "position":2, "type":"communityChest"}, 
        {"name":"Baltic Avenue", "price":60, "position":3, "type":"property"},
        {"name":"Income Tax", "price":0, "type":"incomeTax", "position":4},
        {"name":"Reading Railroad", "price":200, "position":5, "type":"railroad"}, 
        {"name":"Oriental Avenue", "price":100, "position":6, "type":"property"}, 
        {"name":"Chance", "price":0, "position":7, "type":"chance"},
        {"name":"Vermont Avenue", "price":100, "position":8, "type":"property"}, 
        {"name":"Connecticut Avenue", "price":120, "position":9, "type":"property"}, 
        {"name":"Jail", "price":0, "position":10, "type":"jail"}]
}};

function getData() {
  return data.components.boardSpaces.filter(function(space) {
    return space.price === 0;
  });
}

var terminal = document.getElementById('terminal');

getData().forEach(function(space) {
  terminal.innerHTML += space.name + ' - ' + space.price + '\n';
});
```

```css
pre {
  border: 1px solid gray;
  background: lightgray;
  padding: 15px;
  margin: 32px;
}
```

```html
<pre id="terminal"></pre>
```

Answer (score 2):

What about using `forEach` to go through the array? I think the syntax is easier to understand:

```
response.data.components.boardSpaces.forEach(function (element,index) {
    if(element.price !== 0) { // if not zero ...
        self.board.push(index); //or element, not sure what you are trying to store
    };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue was you were using `for ...  in` where you should have used `forEach`:

```
  response.data.components.boardSpaces.forEach(function (space) {
      if(space.price === 0) {
          self.board.push(space);
      };
  });
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/ZakpSlMrIvl0sKRpxyT9?p=preview